# How to edit current macro to search only column C for a value greater than one specified

Tags: vba, excel

I'm not sure how to go about this, but basically this will search through a folder of excel files and create a new sheet with a list and link for the files that contain a specified search term. MY question is, how would I edit this to only look at a specified column (e.g., column C). Also, how would I make it to search for numbers greater than the one specified (e.g., my excel files have lab values in column C, and i'm trying to find the excel files that have values greater than ^)

```
Sub SearchWKBooks()
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim myfolder As String
Dim Str As String
Dim a As Single
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set WS = Sheets.Add

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Show
    myfolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

Str = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Search string:", Title:="Search all workbooks in a folder", Type:=2)

If Str = "" Then Exit Sub

WS.Range("A1") = "Search string:"
WS.Range("B1") = Str
WS.Range("A2") = "Path:"
WS.Range("B2") = myfolder
WS.Range("A3") = "Workbook"
WS.Range("B3") = "Worksheet"
WS.Range("C3") = "Cell Address"
WS.Range("D3") = "Link"

a = 0

Value = Dir(myfolder)
Do Until Value = ""
    If Value = "." Or Value = ".." Then
    Else
        If Right(Value, 3) = "xls" Or Right(Value, 4) = "xlsx" Or Right(Value, 4) = "xlsm" Then
            On Error Resume Next
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=myfolder & Value, Password:="zzzzzzzzzzzz"
            If Err.Number > 0 Then
                WS.Range("A4").Offset(a, 0).Value = Value
                WS.Range("B4").Offset(a, 0).Value = "Password protected"
                a = a + 1
            Else
                On Error GoTo 0
                For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
                        Set c = sht.Cells.Find(Str, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
                        If Not c Is Nothing Then
                            firstAddress = c.Address
                            Do
                                WS.Range("A4").Offset(a, 0).Value = Value
                                WS.Range("B4").Offset(a, 0).Value = sht.Name
                                WS.Range("C4").Offset(a, 0).Value = c.Address
                                WS.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=WS.Range("D4").Offset(a, 0), Address:=myfolder & Value, SubAddress:= _
                                sht.Name & "!" & c.Address, TextToDisplay:="Link"
                                a = a + 1
                                Set c = sht.Cells.FindNext(c)
                            Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
                        End If
                Next sht
            End If
            Workbooks(Value).Close False
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    End If
    Value = Dir
Loop
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line `Set c = sht.Cells.Find(Str, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)` to

```
 Set c = sht.columns(3).Find(Str, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext) - This will look only C column in the specified sheet

If c.value<>vbnullstring and c.value > 10 Then ' Code passes this line if the cell value is more than 10
```

Comment: Are u getting any error ? what is ur exact requirement on secondpart ?

Comment: thanks so much for your reply. search for column 3 works great. Though, the second part of what you said is not working. @Sathish K . I'm not sure what to do for that part. I get what you are trying to do but I get a run-time error 91. I know the dialog box asks what I want to search and it searches for the exact phrase. In my case I am trying to find any numbers higher than the one I specify. Not sure If that changes things. I have a list of lab values and I would like to find ones that are not normal. So I would like to search for one that would be greater than 6, for example.

Comment: it was error 91 after replacing "If Not c Is Nothing Then" with what you had, not sure if that was correct though

Comment: C Columns contains only numbers ?

Comment: It contains both numbers and letters depending on the cell